# I can't switch into hardmode but I can break altars and no hollow spawned

Tags: terraria

I killed WoF (wall of flesh) 5 times already and it won't let me enter hardmode.

I get the pwnhammer, I can destroy altars, but I don't get new ores spawning from destroying the altars and the hollow didn't spawn in my world after beating WoF. Is this a bug or something?

Comment: How are you sure you don't have new ores and hollow didn't spawn?

Comment: becuse i was runing from one side of the map to the other and there were no holow and the your world was blesed whit <ore name> text didnt show up when i destroyed an altar

Comment: Is this for PC, console, or mobile? What version are you running? Are other worlds on this device capable of entering hardmode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode):

> The first three Demon Altars destroyed will trigger the creation of
>   three new Ores, in the following order:
>
> The first destroyed Demon Altar or Crimson Altar will trigger the
>   creation of Cobalt Ore or Palladium Ore. The second destroyed Demon
>   Altar or Crimson Altar will trigger the creation of Mythril Ore or
>   Orichalcum Ore. The third destroyed Demon Altar or Crimson Altar will
>   trigger the creation of Adamantite Ore or Titanium Ore.

Did you destroy at least 3? It also says that Hallow and Crimson/Corruption should spawn upon its death, not the altars. If that's not the case, i would assume it is a bug yes.

Else see [this post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/1rq0z1/so_i_just_beat_the_wall_of_flesh_and_no_hollow/) from someone with a similar issue on reddit.

Comment: yea i destroyed 5 of them and nothing new hapened

Comment: i actualy brought the mushrom hammer now

Comment: and it fixed it. just nead to buy the clemsinator to create holow

Comment: @death3003 how did you buy the Clentaminator without any hardmode stuff?

Comment: @Hugo Zink It seems using the mushroom hammer to destroy the altars allowed him to obtain hardmode ores.

Answer (score 0):

Your save is likely to have been corrupted, either by tampering or just regular gameplay. Thousands of people have issues with this.

I would recommend starting a new world and going on ; from there you should keep your character. *Any further gameplay might corrupt your character save*.

This is just my opinion based on hours of reddit posts.

Comment: if you read the comments on the other answer it says he has already fixed the problem

Answer (score -2):

I **THINK** that is only a glitch for mobile, but I will try and look into those errors and tell you when I get it. ***=)***

Comment: Thanks, but this would be better posted when you've looked into it and have a workaround/solution :).