# I cant seem to find the hallow in hardmode?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I killed the wall of flesh got to hard mode but now cannot find the hallow any answers?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us some more information about your problem? This question is pretty vague, as-is.

Comment: While this is poorly worded, it certainly seems clear to me what he's asking. Mage Xy's answer agrees with my interpretation. Possible duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219164/i-cant-switch-into-hardmode-but-i-can-break-altars-and-no-hollow-spawned/219198#219198 but the circumstances seem like they might be diferent.

Answer (score 3):

Hallow can only affect dirt, stone, and sand. Mud, which the jungle is made up of, can't be Hallowed. (However, the Hallow/Corruption/Crimson can convert mud into dirt, and then spread to the new dirt block. This does not happen during the initial generation of the hardmode biomes though.)

When you kill the Wall of Flesh, a 'V' of Hallow and Corruption/Crimson appears in your world. Usually this is pretty easy to find... however, if one side of the V ends up being in the jungle, you might not see the new Hallow/Corruption/Crimson biome until you dig down quite a bit, since the jungle is not overwritten when the V is created.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't find Hallow try to destroy some demon altars with your PwnHammer.

Upon destroying a demon altar more corruption/crimson and hallow spawn alongside some new ores in your world.

Comment: While technically correct, there's only a 33% chance of getting a single tile of Hallow from each Altar destroyed, which isn't really going to help in finding a Hallow biome without a lot of waiting and luck.

Comment: @Michaellogg Did they change that? I remember my world being flooded after I went on an altar destruction spree.

Comment: [It's always only been one block per altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar). Of course, with a 66% chance of one or the other per altar, then plenty of waiting afterwards for it to spread, especially if you haven't slowed that down by killing Plantera, breaking a bunch of Altars will *eventually* get you a lot more Corruption and Hallow.